# JAXB with parent child pointers

Tags: java, json, jaxb, json-deserialization

Deserialization of a parent child structure from json is simple using JAXB. But imagine the tree should have an object reference to the parent. How would you create that?

Example :

```
@XmlRootElement public Node {
  @XmlElement String text;
  @XmlElement List<Node> children;
  @XmlTransient Node parent;
}
```

This will create a nice nested Json in the form of

{ Node: {text: "parent", children: [ {text: "onechild"} ] }

But how do I get the **Node parent** field set?
The only approach I found is to add an afterSerialization() method that walks the tree and does set the parent field.

```
afterSerialization() {
  for (Node child : children) {
    child.parent = this;
    child.afterSerialization();
  }
}
```

The preferred way would be a constructor for the Node in the form of

```
public Node(Node child) {
  this.parent = child;
}
```

But this constructor cannot be used with JAXB. 
Am I missing a feature or is the afterSerialization() the only choice?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can add the `afterUnmarshal(Unmarshaller unmarshaller, Object parent)` method to you classes. See [Unmarshal Event Callbacks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html#unmarshalEventCallback). Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks, that is definitely something I did not know. I believe this method is exactly what I was looking for.